# Subgradient inequality for strongly convex functions

Tags: convergence-divergence, optimization, convex-analysis

I need some help to follow the argument made [here](https://blogs.princeton.edu/imabandit/2013/04/04/orf523-strong-convexity/) which says that
$$
f(x_t) - f(x^*) \geq \frac{\alpha}{2}\|x_t-x^*\|^2
$$
if $f$ is $\alpha$ strongly convex and $x^*$ the minimizer of $f$.

From the definition of strong convexity we get
\begin{align}
f(x) -f(y) &\leq g_x^T(x-y)-\frac{\alpha}{2}\|x_t-x^*\|^2\\
f(y) -(x) &\geq g_x^T(y-x)+\frac{\alpha}{2}\|x_t-x^*\|^2
\end{align}
for all $x,y$ and subgradient $g_x$ of $f$ at $x$. Especially for $x=x^*$.

Obviously we have to show that $g_{x^*}^T(y-x^*) \geq 0$.

If the $f$ is continuous then the set of subgradients is $\partial f(x) = \{\nabla f(x)\}$ and $g_{x^*} = \nabla f(x^*) = 0$ by optimiality of $x^*$. However I cannot see how this follows for non-continuous $f$.

Comment: For non-continuous function, you have to verify its convexity piecewisely.

Comment: There is a definition of strong convexity which does not depend on continuity.

Comment: If $x^*$ is a minimizer of $f$, then by definition of subgradient $0 \in \partial f(x^*)$.

Comment: Yes, $0$ is one element in the set of subgradients. Can you elaborate on how $g_{x^*}^T(y-x^*) \geq 0$ follows for all $g_{x^*} \in \partial f(x^*)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One definition of strong convexity is that if $f$ is $\alpha$ strongly convex, then for all $y,x$ and for all $g \in \partial f(x)$.
$$
f(y)-f(x) \ge g^T(y-x) + \frac{\alpha}{2}\|y-x\|^2
$$
The claimed statement is just a special case of the above equation. Note that if $x^*$ is a minimum of $f$, then $0 \in \partial f(x^*)$. So we can plug in $x=x^*$ and $g=0$ to the above and conclude that the following is true for all $y$: 
$$
f(y)-f(x^*) \ge \frac{\alpha}{2}\|y-x^*\|^2
$$
This is simply a weaker statement than strong convexity. I think you're getting confused by trying to prove that it's equivalent to strong convexity.

Comment: Isn't it necessary that the inequality holds for all $g$, not just the special case $g=0$? $g^T(y-x^*)$ could be negative for some $g \neq 0$ and the conclusion would be wrong.

Comment: The claim is just a special case. If you plugged in different subgradients you would get different conclusions.

Comment: Here's a simple abstract example. Suppose $P$ is some function of variables $a,b$ with the property that $P(a,b) \ge 0$ for all $a,b$. Further suppose that $Q$ is a function of $a$ where $Q(a) = P(a, 0)$. Then we can conclude $Q(a) \ge 0$ for all $a$. Then your objection is equivalent to saying that we haven't proved anything for all $b$, but that's irrelevant to the claim.

Comment: Good explanation. I was too focused to show it for all subgradients.